# android StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, string, hex

I've got a function where I get a signed decimal value and I convert it into a hex value. With this hex value an other hex values I create a hex string for wich I need to calculate the Checksum:

But I may have something wrong because i'm getting the next message in the Logcat:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=19, index=19 at hexStringToByteArray.
```

At a first look, it seems that the problem should be in that the message length should be max 15, but I don't now why is getting this because the message is 9byte long.

This is the code:

```
savedProgress = (value between 0 and 100)

int_value = ((savedProgress * 20480) / 100) * -1;
hex_value = Integer.toString(int_value, 16);

String message_part = send_command(05)+num_byte_thread(07)+num_byte_variable(02)+pos_reg_hex1(5af2ff1f)+hex_value1(-2733 for example);



private String CalcChecksum (String message) {

    /**Get string's bytes*/
    byte[] byte_calc = hexStringToByteArray(message);
    byte b_checksum = 0;

    for (int byte_index = 0; byte_index < byte_calc.length; byte_index++) {
        b_checksum += byte_calc[byte_index];
    }

    int d_checksum = b_checksum;  //Convert byte to int(2 byte)
    int c2_checksum = 256 - d_checksum;  //Hacer complemento a 2
    String hexString = Integer.toHexString(c2_checksum);  //Convertir el entero (decimal) a hexadecimal

    return hexString;
}

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

I think that having a negative hex value maybe has something to do with this problem.

Comment: Hint: What index will `i+1` point to when `len` is odd?

Comment: Sorry @laalto but i'm a little new in java and android and i would apreciate if you can explain me a little bit how to solve this and what do you reffer with it.